# linting error for angularjs HTML template

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext2

I am trying to use sublimeLinter-Html-Tidy to the following angular template:

```
        <div class="empty-panel" ng-show="feeds != null && feeds.length == 0 && part_loading_done">
            <i class="icon-time"></i><br>
            <span>nothing changed</span>
        </div>
```

The linter gives me this error for "&&" in the Angular directive attribute.

> "unescaped & which should be written as &;"

How should I configure the sublimeLinter-Html-Tidy not to flag this as potential problem?

Comment: <span>&</span>
<span>&amp;</span> are displayed the same. Why should I escape "&"?

Comment: Do you have any plugin for angularJS in sublimeText2 ?

Comment: I use AngularJS Snippets. But it is not related to this warning message by SublimeLinter-Html-Tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real error. Is detecting it as HTML and not as javascript. It's telling you that its better to put an HTML character `&amp;` instead of '&'.

---

If you dont want tidy change your character & for `&amp;` you can edit the user config file in Preferences > Package Settings > Html Tidy > Settings - User

```
{
  "quote-ampersand": false
}
```

Comment: I know it is not an error, just a warning. Do you know how to configure the Linter not to flag this warning?

Comment: Here is the guide http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html, then turn to false the value quote-nbsp in the options: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#quote-nbsp

Comment: "htmltidy": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [{"quote-nbsp": "no"}] ... If I do this, the whole HTML linter is not working right. How do I configure the Tidy in sublimeLinter?

Comment: I tried the config here:https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-html-tidy/issues/6 but it is not working.